# How to generate Clickable popup box?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

[image]

Hi all, Do anyone know how to generate this kind of popup box using jQuery or any other library. The popup box should be clickable until mouse over it.

Comment: You need to make an attempt at doing this yourself first, and post code that you have tried so far. We cannot create the entire thing for you. We can only assist in specific issues you encounter while developing your solution.

Comment: http://qtip2.com/demos

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Tooltip widget provided by the jQuery UI library.
http://jqueryui.com/tooltip

Comment: yes. Im currently using it instead of a popup box.Does anyone know how to made it clickable..??

Comment: It's easy! If you want to show tooltip box on click so you should use click event in jQuery and then do anything you want.